# rs232>Arduino >cement pump

Tags: arduino

The load cell(withstand 200kG) is connected through a XK3190-A12+E indicator and the data can be read through RS232.

However, the question is:-

How can I get the data from RS232 serial port which connected from weighing scale (load cell - withstand 200kg) to Arduino and from Arduino send a signal to control an AC cement pump?

Can someone please advice. Thank you:)

Comment: Try on http://arduino.stackexchange.com/, sounds like a pure arduino problem

Comment: Or get a PLC which is the normal solition for such an industrial problem.

Answer (score 0):

arduino has a UART but you'll need a UART to RS232 converter (like `MAX232`) to interface with an RS232 device) to control the mixer motor a relay or contactor seems ideal.

Comment: does rs232 to TTL adapter more suitable in this case as the load cell indicator is 5 pin MIDI to rs232(female) ?

Comment: that sounds like the same thing with a different name.

Comment: Section 2.3.3 of the User Manual shows that this has nothing much to do with MIDI; the electrical signals are said to be RS-232. So you would indeed need an RS-232/TTL converter.